# Password Encoding Problem in New Python Environment

Tags: python, utf-8, codec

I recently replaced a computer and have reinstalled Anaconda Python 3.7.

I also have a install of MySQL and new passwords.

I am using Pycharm IDE

I am trying to access MySQL as follows:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:%MyPassword@localhost:3306/MySchema')
```

where %MyPassword is the MySQL password and

where MySchema is the MySQL schema

However, when running the script I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Python 3+ is supposed to default to UTF - so why am I getting a latin-1 codec error?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using? 5.7 defaults to latin-1, so you might need to set a charset on your connection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using the '%' character at the beginning (or inside) a password is illegal or if it is some kind of bug.  I used another account on the db with special characters inside the password and not the '%' and it provided access.